# .addClass not working

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add a class to a div using .addClass()

Here is how I am trying to do it:

```
<script>
$("#circle").hover(function() {
    ("#circle").addClass("new_style");
});
</script>
```

and I have this div

```
<div id="circle" class="lol"></div>
```

Upon inspecting the element and and viewing the console I can see the error

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Object #circle has no method 'addClass' "
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You missed a `$` before `("#circle")`:

```
$("#circle").hover(function() {
    $("#circle").addClass("new_style");
});
```

However, you don't need to re-query the DOM for that element at all!

```
$("#circle").hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass("new_style");
});
```

And even then, you don't need to re-jQuery-ify that object. Reuse the jQuery object for less of a performance hit:

```
var $circle = $("#circle");

$circle.hover(function() {
    $circle.addClass("new_style");
});
```

---

Interestingly, neither [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) nor [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/) caught this sloppy error.

Comment: Also, should add the wrapper $(function(){ //code goes here.  });